# When would pointer assignment and assignment by value produce the same effect?

Tags: c, pointers

When would pointer assignment and assignment by value produce the same effect?

For example, suppose I have two pointers pointing to two `int`s:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, *pa = &a, *pb = &b;
```

Then if I have

```
pa = pb;
```

, when would this produce the same effect (i.e., make `*pa == *pb`) as

```
a = b;
```

?

In what situations would this cause problems and writing

```
a = b;
```

be necessary to make `*pa == *pb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pa = pb` only affects code that accesses the data via the variable `pa`. Any code that uses the variable `a` is unaffected. Just because one particular pointer that used to point to `a` no longer points to it, doesn't change anything about `a`.

```
pa = pb;
printf("a=%d, *pa=%d\n", a, *pa);  // prints 1, 2
```

If `a` later changes, that doesn't affect the value obtained via `pa`.

```
a = 3;
printf("a=%d, *pa=%d\n", a, *pa);  // prints 3, 2
```

Conversely, if `b` changes, that doesn't affect the value in `a`.

```
a = 3;
b = 4;
printf("a=%d, *pa=%d\n", a, *pa);  // prints 3, 4
```

What you call “assignment by pointer” is in fact an assignment *of a* pointer. It doesn't do anything to the thing the pointer points to.
Assigning to a variable changes the value of that variable. Assigning to a variable that contains a pointer to another variable changes what the pointer variable points to, no more, no less.

Comment: very nice, concise way of putting it

Answer (score 2):

`pa = pb` will never have the same effect as `a = b`.  The first one changes what address `pa` points to so that it now equals `&b` and `*pa` equals `b`.  The second assignment changes the value of `a` (and thus of `*pa`), but `pa` will continue to refer to the address of `a`, which hasn't changed.

Comment: See my answer. I list some conditions in which `*pa` could be the same as `*pb`, so you can't say "never".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the initial pointer diagram with example addresses shown and the number in the circle the value in the memory at that address:

### `pa` ⟶ ①<sup>0x0</sup>

### `pb` ⟶ ②<sup>0x1</sup>

#### Case 1: Pointer Assignment

Pointer assignment,

```
pa = pb;
```

, would mean this:

### `pa` ↘                ①<sup>0x0</sup>

### `pb` ⟶ ②<sup>0x1</sup>

, i.e., `pa` and `pb` both point to the address 0x1. One could change what's stored in 0x0, mistakenly thinking he's changing `a` or `b` or `*pa` or `*pb`, but 0x0 has been "orphaned."

#### Case 2: Assignment by Value

If, starting with the initial pointer configuration above, one instead assigns by value,

```
a = b;
```

, then the pointer diagram becomes:

### `pa` ⟶ ②<sup>(0x0)</sup>

### `pb` ⟶ ②<sup>(0x1)</sup>

This is a sort of copy because some other code in the program could change what's stored in 0x0 or 0x1 and thus make it no longer true that `*pa == *pb`.

So, to answer the question "*When would pointer assignment produce the same effect* [viz., that `*pa == *pb`] *as assignment by value?*," it would be, for case

1. If nothing changes the contents of adrress 0x0, thinking 0x0 is still `a` or `*pa`.
2. If nothing changes the contents of 0x0 or 0x1
   or
   if the contents of
   0x0 and 0x1 are simultaneously changed to the same value.